# How to change alignment of toolbat Ext JS

Tags: extjs, toolbar

I have a toolbar with some buttons. I want the buttons in the toolbar to be aligned to the right. How can I do that ? This is the code

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'top',
    buttonAlign: 'right', // This one does not wrok
    align: 'right', // This one does neither
    items: [{
        text: 'Foo1'
    }, {
        text: 'Foo2'
    }, {
        text: 'Foo3'
   }]
}, {
   // Some other items
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Ext.toolbar.Fill` before your other buttons:

```
items: [
    { xtype: 'tbfill' }, 
    { text: 'Foo1' }, 
    { text: 'Foo2' }, 
    { text: 'Foo3' }
]
```

A shortcut for this is to use `'->'`:

```
items: [
    '->', 
    { text: 'Foo1' }, 
    { text: 'Foo2' }, 
    { text: 'Foo3' }
]
```